# Слово "картошка"

Tags: этимология

Картошка появилась на Руси относительно недавно, значит, и слово это достаточно новое. Но откуда оно взялось в русском языке?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Картошка - производное от КАРТОФЕЛЬ. Заимствовано из нем. яз. в XVIII в. Нем. Kartoffel «картофель» возникло в результате видоизменения более стар. нем. Tarfuffel, заимствованного из итал. языка. Итал. tarfufolo значит «трюфель», т. с. «гриб округлой формы, растущий под землей без корня и ствола». По этимол. итал. название восходит к лат. terratuber «земляная шишка», образованному сложением terra «земля» и tuber «шишка», 
«трюфель». Сущ. Kartoffel > картофель — собств. «трюфель», «земляная шишка» — немцы использовали для названия нового распространившегося в Европе овоща, впервые привезенного в XVI в. испанцами из Америки. (Цыганенко, Фасмер).

Интересна этимология слова БУЛЬБА от *буньба* "картофель", псковск., смол., южн., также *гулба* -- то же, диал., укр., бел. *бульба*. Заимств. через польск. bulba, bulwa, чеш. bulva из нем. Bolle "клубень, луковица". То есть с появлением нового овоща(?) нужно было придумать ему название. Название давали по сходству с тем, что известно: с трюфелем (благородно!) или с луковицей, клубнем (без изысков).

Comment: Дополнительно:
в англ. языке картофель называется potato. Это слово явно совсем никакого отношения к _Kartoffel_ не имеет. Оказывается, оно образовано от исп. _patata_, а оно в свою очередь от гаитянского _batata_ (сладкая картошка). Именно испанцы завезли картофель в Европу. Далее обычный картофель был по ошибке назван _Virginia potato_ или _bastard potato_.
Фр. _pomme de terre_ ("земляное яблоко") и шв. jordpäron ("земляная груша") названия так же говорят о том, что исконного названия у данного овоща в Европе не было и все придумали на свой лад.